# java, sort array. how can i log individual execution times from large iterations to average them?

Tags: java, sorting, timer, runtime, iteration

i'm writing a bubble sort algorithm that needs to sort and resort up to 1000 times and average the execution times, and i've got the program working for the most part, it makes an array of size n, fills the array with random number of range x-->y, sorts the numbers and reiterates the program n times, gives the run time for each iteration. im stuck on the problem of pulling individual runtimes for iterations above say..25, for example, so that i can average them so that i dont have to graph a million rumbers. not sure if i should create a new class to accomplish this and import it in or what, im brand new to programming. any help will be appreciated, none of the other questions i looked at had an adequate answer.

```
    package termproject;

import java.util.Scanner;                  //call up classes to be used in the program
import java.util.Random;

public class TermProject {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n;                     //designate variables
    int randomNumMin;
    int randomNumMax;
    int iteration;
    int swap;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);          //create scanner

    System.out.print("How many numbers should be in the array? ");      //get input from user to designate the size of the array to be used
    n = scan.nextInt();                                                   //this method allows for ease of use when changing the perameters of the program

    System.out.print("What should the minimum value for the array be? "); //user input, same reasoning, ease of use when changing perameters
    randomNumMin = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("What about the maximum value? ");
    randomNumMax = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("How many times do you want to run the program? ");  //user input to designate how many times the program should execute
    iteration = scan.nextInt();

    int[] ar = new int[n];    //create new array

    Random random = new Random();  //create foundation for random number generation
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int r = 0; r < iteration; r++) {   //tell program to start iterations here and run repitions
        System.out.println();                 //up to the corresponding parse
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(r + 1 + ". " + "The program will sort this array: ");    //a label for the unsorted array

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ar[i] = random.nextInt(ar.length);    //populate unsorted array with randomly generated numbers

            System.out.print("   " + ar[i] + ", ");    //print out the randomly generated array
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {           //sort the previously generated array
            for (int d = 0; d < n - i - 1; d++) {     //bubblesort method
                if (ar[d] > ar[d + 1]) {
                    swap = ar[d];
                    ar[d] = ar[d + 1];
                    ar[d + 1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");          //print out a label for the sorted array
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("   After Bubblesorting the array becomes: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //populate the array with sorted information and print out
        {
            System.out.print("   " + ar[i] + ", ");
        }

        long executeTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;


        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(+executeTime/1E9 +" Seconds");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your usage of the word runtime will create confusion. I would use something like executionTime.

Comment: Please prepare the code before asking a question (i.e. at least format it properly).

Comment: reformatted it, made sure it compiles and it does. like i said, new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I am understanding you correctly, but is this what you want? To simply store the time it takes to execute each sort and finally take their average.

```
import java.util.Scanner;                  //call up classes to be used in the program
import java.util.Random;

public class TermProject {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

   int n;                     //designate variables
   int randomNumMin;
   int randomNumMax;
   int iteration;
   int swap;

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);          //create scanner

   System.out.print("How many numbers should be in the array? ");      //get input from user to designate the size of the array to be used
   n = scan.nextInt();                                                   //this method allows for ease of use when changing the parameters of the program

   System.out.print("What should the minimum value for the array be? "); //user input, same reasoning, ease of use when changing parameters
   randomNumMin = scan.nextInt();

   System.out.print("What about the maximum value? ");
   randomNumMax = scan.nextInt();

   System.out.print("How many times do you want to run the program? ");  //user input to designate how many times the program should execute
   iteration = scan.nextInt();

   int[] ar = new int[n];    //create new array

   Random random = new Random();  //create foundation for random number generation

   long startTime; 
   double[] eTime = new double[iteration]; // array used to store execution times

    for (int r = 0; r < iteration; r++) {   //tell program to start iterations here and run repitions
       System.out.println();                 //up to the corresponding parse
       System.out.println("\n");
       System.out.println(r + 1 + ". " + "The program will sort this array: ");    //a label for the unsorted array

       startTime = System.nanoTime(); //store the current time when starting the loop

       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           ar[i] = random.nextInt(ar.length);    //populate unsorted array with randomly generated numbers

           System.out.print("   " + ar[i] + ", ");    //print out the randomly generated array
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {           //sort the previously generated array
           for (int d = 0; d < n - i - 1; d++) {     //bubblesort method
               if (ar[d] > ar[d + 1]) {
                   swap = ar[d];
                   ar[d] = ar[d + 1];
                   ar[d + 1] = swap;
               }
           }
       }
       System.out.println("\n");          //print out a label for the sorted array
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("   After Bubblesorting the array becomes: ");

       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //populate the array with sorted information and print out
       {
           System.out.print("   " + ar[i] + ", ");
       }        

       eTime[r] = (System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1e9; //storing the time in the array
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("\n" + eTime[r] +" Seconds");
   }

   // just printing out the sorting times **************
   System.out.println();
   int itNo = 1;
   for(Double d: eTime)
   {
       System.out.println("Iteration " + itNo + " time is:" + d);
       itNo++; 
   }   

   //Averaging the times **************************
   System.out.println();
   double average = 0.0;
   for(double d: eTime)
   {
       average += d;
   }

   average /= eTime.length; //storing the average in the average variable.

   System.out.println("The average execution time is:" + average + "."); 

 }

}
```

Hope this is what you had in mind?

Comment: that works perfectly, it didn't occur to me to use another array to store the times. i was thinking along the lines of pulling the times and listing them or something. thank you for your help

Comment: Now you can work on making the randomNumMin + Max that are entered actually alter the random numbers generated to populate your arrays. :)

Comment: ive been looking at that, im assuming that the random numbers that i get are in a range between 1 and the size of the array with the way that i have it now eh?

Comment: yes, so you can change `ar[i] = random.nextInt(ar.length);` to `ar[i] = random.nextInt(randomNumMax+1);`, you also can use a loop to generate a new number if `ar[i] < randomNumMin`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should probably generate the random numbers and populate the array before you start keeping track of execution times, since it isn't part of the sort. Also it will probably take a while to get up to speed when your program is first executed so a few trial sorts might help with accuracy.

Comment: you'll have to excuse me, im still coming up to speed, im not sure i understand how to do that, if i separate the sort iterations from the code that keeps track of the ex. times wouldnt that end up giving me the total runtime of the program again? if thats a stupid question just remember im in my first programming class and its java and its a little complex at this point.

Comment: wait, i thought about that after the last comment, did you mean i should moved the line of code that starts the timer from where it is to underneath the code that populates the array with random numbers?

Comment: Yes, only include the actual sorting of the array, not the code that populates the array. You can leave it as is if you want to calculate total time, or alter it some if you only want to calculate the average sort times.